# How to install h5py with pypy?

Tags: python, pip, conda, h5py, openai-gym

I'm trying to install h5py to use with pypy. (In an ubuntu docker container)

I tried (each on a fresh install):

installing with conda (Miniforge):

```
conda install h5py
pypy -mpip install gym psutil pandas h5py
```

results in

```
  File "/root/miniforge-pypy3/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _errors
ImportError: cannot import name '_errors'
```

installing with pip (as well in Miniforge, as in "normal" downloaded pypy):

```
pypy -mpip install gym psutil pandas h5py
```

results in

```
  File "/pypy3.6-v7.3.2-linux64/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from . import h5a, h5d, h5ds, h5f, h5fd, h5g, h5r, h5s, h5t, h5p, h5z, h5pl
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5d
ValueError: array.array size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 24 from PyObject
```

What could I be doing wrong? What could I try to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you looked at this issue on github: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/753

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help. However, I don't really understand "use pip, not setup.py". I'm using conda install, pypy -mpip install and pip install - is one of them bad?

Comment: As per the issue it seems... this may be a conflict arising from installation of different versions of h5py. Can you try creating a new virtual environment and check if you are able to install there? Then we can fix your issue in the current environment